# Script change admin password

Tags: php, user-input, insert-update

I write a script to change admin password via an input 
But the problem is when i write the new password  . 
it change in the all tables that’s mean that The new password become the new password of all users and i want it just for the user that i chose 
please if you can help me 
this is the script :

```
                  <form method="post">
                   <div style="padding-left:40px;" class="azer" class="adm">
                    <ul style="list-style : none; " >
                        <li style="padding-left:5px;">
                            <h6  style="float:left; ">new password :</h6>                           
                            <input  style="float:left; margin-left:10px; " type="text" name="zd_pass"  placeholder="*******"> 
                        </li>
                        <li><input style="margin-left:10px;" type="submit" name="save" value="save" class="btn btn-info" ></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
           <?php             
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $get_id = "select * from admin where zd_id='$id'";
    $run_id = mysqli_query($db,$get_id);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_id) > 0){
      if(isset($_POST['save'])){    
               $zd_id = @$_POST['zd_id'];   
               $zd_pass = @$_POST['zd_pass'];
          $update = "update admin set zd_pass='$zd_pass'";
          $run_update = mysqli_query($db,$update);
   if(isset($run_update)){
  }}   }}  ?>
```

Comment: your update queqy doesn't have `where` condition, that's why it updates the whole set

Comment: I'm curious. Is this site live or intended to go live? I hope you've taken using a safe hashing function for password storage into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit the update to a single row, just the same way you did with the previous select. You do this by setting a WHERE clause like this, otherwise it will update your entire database.

Also your test after you submit the update to the database for execution will not be reliable. You should change it as below

```
$update = "update admin set zd_pass='$zd_pass' WHERE zd_id='$id'";

$run_update = mysqli_query($db,$update);
if( $run_update !== FALSE) {
    // the update worked
} else {
    // the update failed
}
```

Comment: ...like this, otherwise it will update your entire database. was to be my edit there Smokey.

Comment: Oh HI Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: am going to re-edit now lol so don't touch anything haha. Edit: done ;-)

Comment: I am sitting on my hands

Comment: *lol* - don't stay that way too long, they'll get numb. Then you won't be able to tell who got their wish.